# VB.net how to subtract date with another date and get a whole number of days

Tags: vb.net, date, subtraction

i use MS Access for my database.
I have 2 columns holding 2 different dates

example
column 1 = 8/7/2016
column 2 = 8/11/2016

i want to subtract 8/11/2016 to 8/7/2016 and get a whole number.
in this example i should be getting 4. What i intend to do is to use the result to compute for something.

Comment: in VB, in a SQL query, where are you looking at doing this?

Comment: in VB. I was imagining to fetch the data dates first and then subtract the 2 dates.

Comment: Check out [`DateTime.Subtract([date])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.subtract(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Date(Time)s can directly be substracted resulting in a [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) object which has `Days` or `TotalDays` properties

```
Dim result = (#11/08/2016# - #07/08/2016#).Days
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DateDiff](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateDiff-Function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f)

```
Days = DateDiff("d", #07/08/2016#, #11/08/2016#)
```

or in an access sql query:

```
DateDiff('d', [DateCol1], [DateCol2])
```